# Spark - How update a DBTable with data from DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Scenario: I read a file from a local hard drive, which contains details about published documents. The records represents some new published docs and some updated info about already published docs. Say the pub_id is the key and doesn't change. I read this file data to a data frame and want to append the data to publishers database table. New records must get appended and existing records must get updated.

How do I do this in Spark? Can I do this without reading the entire content of publishers table?

Comment: I think you'll have to be more specific. It is really hard to figure out what you want right now. Maybe you can add example input and expected output?

Comment: Please make it an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31685743/edit) to the question not a comment.